# Main site collection checked out to a user?

Tags: error, site-collection, check-out

I'm getting ready to build out a basic intranet for my company, and on our main site collection I'm getting the message that it is checked out to an individual who does not have owner-level permissions. I know documents can be checked in or out, but I've never heard about an entire site collection being checked out.

Does anyone know how I can fix this and ensure it doesn't happen again?

[image]

---

Ok, so DUH on my part regarding how I override the checkout. Just fixed it in the page ribbon. But I could use some help in ensuring I have my settings right to where no one but myself and other owners can adjust/edit anything on the site. It needs to be completely closed.

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The site collection is not checked out. It is not possible to check out a site collection. What has happened is that the file `Home.aspx` in the SitePages library is checked out. Anyone with contribute permissions are allowed to do this.

You got two options two limit other users to be able to do this:

- Change their permissions from contribute to read on the entire site
- Set unique permissions on the sitepages library and change the permissions to read on all users

Answer (score 0):

You can change the permissions on site pages library. 
You need to click on the gear icon that will take you to site settings and then click on view all site contents. 
Navigate to site pages library. Open permissions for this library by clicking on settings.

Break the inheritance for this site pages.

**Modify your other contributors group and rest of the group whom you think need not have edit access to this page to read access. 
(please don't modify read permissions)**

That will allow you to have unique permissions for the site pages and this way you can secure your site pages.